# SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns not cascading properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

I have three SharePoint 2016 lists:

- Organizations
- Departments
- Groups

Groups are sorted by Department and Departments are sorted by Organization.

The title field in each list is used for the name of the group, org or dept and there is a dropdown in each list to select the parent of that respective item.

In one of my forms, the user is supposed to select the org, dept and group who owns a specific software title.  I am attempting to use SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns to show only the departments for the selected org, but it isn't doing anything at all.

The relavent fields in the form are:

```
<td valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
  <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
    <nobr>Organization<span class="ms-formvalidation"> *</span></nobr>
  </H3>
</td>
<td valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
  <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff9{$Pos}" ControlMode="New"
   FieldName="Organization" 
   __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('i',concat('ff9',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@Organization')}"/>
  <SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" id="ff9description{$Pos}" FieldName="Organization" ControlMode="New"/>
</td>
<td valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
  <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
    <nobr>Department<span class="ms-formvalidation"> *</span></nobr>
  </H3>
</td>
<td valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
  <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff10{$Pos}" ControlMode="New"
  FieldName="Department"
  __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('i',concat('ff10',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@Department')}"/>
  <SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" id="ff10description{$Pos}" FieldName="Department" ControlMode="New"/>
</td>
```

The Javascript I'm using is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
        relationshipList: "{xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}",
        relationshipListParentColumn: "Organization",
        relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",
        parentColumn: "Organization",
        childColumn: "Department",
        debug: true
    });
});
```

I've loaded jQuery 3.2.1 and jQuery.SPServices-2014.02.min.js.  I'm getting no errors in Chrome console, it just isn't doing anything at all.  If I put a break at $().SPServices, it does hit so I know it's being called.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is your list relationship model? Departments have lookup to organizations and groups have both lookup for organizations and departments?

Comment: I recommend you check this thread if one of the fields are required.  Keep in mind this library was built for 2007/2010 http://spservices.codeplex.com/discussions/657744

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking into consideration that you didn't provided your data structure, i've brought mine ;)

Use this PowerShell script to create structure in a specific site collection:

```
$web = get-spweb <YOUR URL>
$template = $web.ListTemplates | where name -eq 'Custom List'
$organizationsListId = $web.Lists.Add("Organizations", "", $template)
$departmentsListId = $web.Lists.Add("Departments", "", $template)
$groupsListId = $web.Lists.Add("Groups", "", $template)

$organizationsLookup = $web.Fields.AddLookup("OrganizationsLookup", $organizationsListId, $false)
$departmentsLookup = $web.Fields.AddLookup("DepartmentsLookup", $departmentsListId, $false)

$organizations = $web.Lists[$organizationsListId]
$departments = $web.Lists[$departmentsListId]
$groups = $web.Lists[$groupsListId]

$departments.Fields.Add($web.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("OrganizationsLookup"))
$groups.Fields.Add($web.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("DepartmentsLookup"))
$groups.Fields.Add($web.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("OrganizationsLookup"))

$organizationsLookupInList = $departments.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("OrganizationsLookup");
$organizationsLookupInList.LookupField = "Title"
$organizationsLookupInList.Update()

$departmentsLookupInList = $groups.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("DepartmentsLookup");
$departmentsLookupInList.LookupField = "Title"
$departmentsLookupInList.Update()

$organizationsLookupInList1 = $groups.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("OrganizationsLookup");
$organizationsLookupInList1.LookupField = "Title"
$organizationsLookupInList1.Update()

function AddListItem($list, $title)
{
    $itm = $list.AddItem()
    $itm["Title"] = $title 
    $itm.Update()
    return $itm
}

function AddListItemDepartments($list, $title, $lookupIdOrg)
{
    $itm = AddListItem $list $title
    $itm["OrganizationsLookup"] = $lookupIdOrg
    $itm.Update();
    return $itm
}

function AddListItemGroups($list, $title, $lookupIdOrg, $lookupIdDep)
{
    $itm = AddListItemDepartments $list $title $lookupIdOrg
    $itm["DepartmentsLookup"] = $lookupIdDep
    $itm.Update();
    return $itm
}

$org1Id = (AddListItem $organizations "AAA NET").ID
$org2Id = (AddListItem $organizations "BBB NET").ID
$org3Id = (AddListItem $organizations "CCC NET").ID
$org4Id = (AddListItem $organizations "DDD NET").ID


$dep1Id = (AddListItemDepartments $departments "Finance" $org1Id).ID
$dep2Id = (AddListItemDepartments $departments "IT" $org1Id).ID
$dep3Id = (AddListItemDepartments $departments "Finance" $org2Id).ID
$dep4Id = (AddListItemDepartments $departments "Social" $org2Id).ID
$dep5Id = (AddListItemDepartments $departments "Fun" $org2Id).ID
$dep6Id = (AddListItemDepartments $departments "Sport" $org2Id).ID
$dep7Id = (AddListItemDepartments $departments "Knowledge" $org3Id).ID
$dep8Id = (AddListItemDepartments $departments "Sport" $org3Id).ID
```

Next:

1. Open groups list newform page.
2. Hit edit page from top-right settings.
3. Edit xsltlistviewformwebpart, attach jquery and spservices to `JSLink` property
   ie:

   `~site/siteassets/jquery-3.2.1.min.js | ~site/siteassets/jquery.SPServices-2014.02.min.js`
4. Add CEWP to page, move it below form webpart and insert your js cascading dropdowns code:

Code (see comments)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
        relationshipList: "{xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}", // Your departments list id
        relationshipListParentColumn: "OrganizationsLookup",
        relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",
        parentColumn: "OrganizationsLookup",
        childColumn: "DepartmentsLookup",
        debug: true
    });
});
```

And this should work (also with jquery 3.2.1)

Comment: Well, your answer led me to the correct code.  Turns out that the parentColumn field in the SPCascadeDropdowns function will try to use a jQuery to find the select element with the title specified in parentColumn.  I thought that the title would be "Organization", but SharePoint was setting the title to "Organization Required Field".

Comment: glad you found it!

Answer (score -1):

Looks like the issue is because you are using `jQuery 3.2.1`.

According to documentation, its recommended that you use `jQuery 1.10 or greater`.

Would recommend that you remove the `3.2.1` version and instead use `1.12` version and then check.

Reference -

[SPServices General documentation](http://sympmarc.github.io/SPServices/general-instructions.html)

[jquery.SPServices-2014.02.js](https://github.com/cdnjs/cdnjs/blob/master/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/2014.02/jquery.SPServices-2014.02.js)

Download link for jQuery - [jQuery.min.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js)

Comment: I verified that SPServices does work with the most recent jQuery.