# Cascade Drop-Dow in Shareponint 2013 not working

Tags: sharepoint

I have two lists:

Clientes-Canal: TITLE
Clientes-Subsegmentacion: TITLE - CANAL (Lookup to Clientes-Canal)
Clientes: where I save all the information

My code:

```js
           $(document).ready(function () {
               $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
                   relationshipList: "Clientes-Subsegmentacion",
                   relationshipListParentColumn: "Clientes-Canal",
                   relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",
                   parentColumn: "Canal",
                   childColumn: "Subsegmentacion",
                   debug: true
               });
           });
```

In my Clientes' list I have two columns, Canal (Lookup to Clientes-Canal), and Subsegmentacion (Lookup to Clientes-Subsegmentacion)

But it's not working.

Error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Answer (score 0):

Here are the docs:

> **relationshipList** The name or GUID of the list which contains the
>   parent/child relationships. If you choose to use the GUID, it should
>   look like: "{E73FEA09-CF8F-4B30-88C7-6FA996EE1706}". Note also that if
>   you use the GUID, you do not need to specify the relatedWebURL if the
>   list is in another site.
>
> **relationshipListParentColumn** The StaticName of the parent column in
>   the relationshipList
>
> **relationshipListChildColumn** The StaticName of the child column in the
>   relationshipList
>
> **parentColumn** The DisplayName of the parent column in the form
>
> **childColumn** The DisplayName of the child column in the form

So, in your case:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
        relationshipList: "Clientes-Subsegmentacion",
        relationshipListParentColumn: "Canal",
        relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",
        parentColumn: "Canal",
        childColumn: "Subsegmentacion",
        debug: true
    });
});
```

Make sure you don't have spelling mistakes, you can also try using `Id` of your `Clientes-Subsegmentacion` list.

Take a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48341452/1498401) on similar question if my answer doesn't help you.